# How to upload Firebase Crashlytics mapping file for React Native?

Tags: firebase, react-native, obfuscation, crashlytics

I am using [rnfirebase.io](https://rnfirebase.io) Firebase Crashlytics. The stack trace is obfuscated, how to upload a mapping file to see the original source code?

Is there an API for it or some SDK support?